# How can I make a long click listener for an AppWidgetHostView

Tags: java, android, widget, onlongclicklistener

I'm making a launcher and I am stuck on making a long click listener for the widgets. I made a class that extends `AppWidgetHost` and another that extends `AppWidgetHostView`. They intercept the touch event and if it's action up it looks and sees if the action down lasted for 400L. It works ok unless there is no button on the widget. For example, the clock widget can not be long pressed.

Here is the implementation of the `longClickListener` on the host view:

```
hostView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(WidgetEdge.this)
            .setTitle("Options")
            .setMessage("Do you want to delete or resize widget?")
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
            .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    removeWidget(hostView);
                    Toast.makeText(WidgetEdge.this, "Widget Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Resize", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    resizeView(hostView);
                }
            }).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the `AppWidgetHostView` class:

```
public class LauncherAppWidgetHostView extends AppWidgetHostView{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    WidgetEdge context;
    private OnLongClickListener longClick;
    private long down;

    public LauncherAppWidgetHostView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = (WidgetEdge) context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener l) {
        this.longClick = l;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean trueOrFalse = false;
        switch(ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                down = System.currentTimeMillis();
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                trueOrFalse = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                boolean upVal = System.currentTimeMillis() - down > 400L;
                if( upVal ) {
                    longClick.onLongClick(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.this);
                    trueOrFalse = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return trueOrFalse;
    }

    @Override
    protected View getErrorView() {
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.appwidget_error, this, false);
    }
}
```

Here is the `AppWidgetHost`:

```
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProviderInfo;
import android.content.Context;

class LauncherAppWidgetHost extends AppWidgetHost {
    LauncherAppWidgetHost(Context context, int hostId) {
        super(context, hostId);
    }

    @Override
    protected AppWidgetHostView onCreateView(Context context, int appWidgetId,
                                             AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidget) {
        return new LauncherAppWidgetHostView(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopListening() {
        super.stopListening();
        clearViews();
    }
}
```

I have tried using the code from [this link](https://github.com/tjlian616/Android-Trebuchet-Launcher-Standalone/blob/master/src/com/cyanogenmod/trebuchet/LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java) but when I tested on the clock widget it launches the `onLongClickListener` twice. Also when the widget is scrolled, without a long press, it would also launch the `onLongClick`. Thank you for any help.

--UPDATE--
I was using the debugger and found out that when using the clock widget the only event intercepted was the first ACTION_DOWN. After that it never picked up the ACTION_UP.

Answer (score 0):

If the widget doesn't behave like a button (so when it can't be clicked) you need to do something more advanced to detect the long click.

You can have a look at https://github.com/willli666/Android-Trebuchet-Launcher-Standalone/blob/master/src/com/cyanogenmod/trebuchet/LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java
If the Apache licence works for your project, you can copy-paste the whole file, you just need to remove `getErrorView()` and the inflater and you're good to go.

The idea is to start a timeout when detecting the initial ACTION_DOWN event, and when the timeout triggers, if the view still has focus, then you can `performLongClick()`.

It's much harder to accomplish than one would expect, but at least this works on all widgets, even those that can't be clicked.